# How nifi distributes data between different nodes?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a nifi cluster with 3 Nodes. I am using a invokeHTTP processor in a flow. Basically, there is a post endpoint that gives me 1 - 2GB JSON data daily which I finally save in POSTGRES. The Flow is working fine, but I am not sure if I am using the whole cluster of three nodes effectively.

Here are two scenarios on which I tested the flow, in these scenarios I just change the 'Execution' mode present in the scheduling tab of invokeHTTP processor from 'All nodes' to 'PRIMARY NODE'

1- With Execution mode 'All nodes', I see 3 requests being passed from invokeHTTP to the next processor. So instead of just 2gb of json response i see 6gb of response being passed to the next processor, Which means all the 3 nodes are doing the same thing, putting unnecessary load on the cluster and the DB.

2- With Execution mode 'Primary Node', I see 1 requests being passed from invokeHTTP to the next processor. But i think in this case only one node is being used and the other 2 nodes are doing nothing, which is not a proper use of the Cluster.

What is the right approach to use the whole cluster?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568114/distribution-of-content-among-cluster-nodes-within-edge-nifi-processors

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is really helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general NiFi does not automatically move data between nodes unless you setup the dataflow to do so. In your situation you only want InvokeHttp to execute on one node so that should be set as primary node only.

After that it depends on whether the response can be broken up into individual pieces. If the 2GB JSON can be split apart into smaller flow files then you can use a load balanced connection to distribute the smaller pieces to the other nodes of the cluster, but if it can't be then you have to run the whole flow on the primary node only.

https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/load-balancing-across-the-cluster

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will add a load balancer and try to split the data across the cluster.

Comment: ok So if some processors in the flow are schedulled on "all nodes" and only the first processor is set to primary node (to fetch a single result) like a listfile for example: Does that mean that the "all node" processors are being executed on the same primary node only, if you don't use a load balanced queue?

Comment: @GherbiHicham yes, the processors in the middle of the flow can always be scheduled for all nodes with run schedule 0 seconds, but if the source processor is primary node only, then only the downstream processors on the primary node will receive data, unless a load balanced connection is used

Comment: @BryanBende +1, thanks, that is not intuitive if you look solely into the nifi interface you would get the idea that NiFi is executed on all nodes.

Comment: @BryanBende So do you need to load balance queues after every processor to make sure that every step of your nifi flow is executed on all nodes or do you only need to do that after you first fetch the file (case of listfile here) and then the data is available on each node? Is the primary node still the only one holding the data after load balancing on the queues?

Comment: @GherbiHicham you should typically only load-balance once after the primary-node only processor, so something like ListXYZ --(LB)--> FetchXYZ, at this point the listings have been distributed to all nodes, and now the Fetch and follow on processing is executing on all nodes